Unable to use both UIautomator2 and flutter together in same script..any solution for this
I am using appium flutter driver for accessing flutter app keys using Javascript..in between I want to access files in mobile directory hence need to access native elements - sdcard/Download folder. When I declare Flutter and UIautomator2 in capabilities script is failing in initialization phase only. Could you please help
const opts = {
  port: 4723,
  capabilities: {
    platformName: "Android",
    'appium:deviceName': "emulator-5554",
    'appium:app': "pkgname",
    'appium:appPackage': "xxx",
    'appium:appActivity': "yyy",
    'appium:autoGrantPermissions': true,
    'appium:automationName': "Flutter"
 }
};

const androidOptions = {
 capabilities: {
    platformName: "Android",
    'appium:deviceName': "emulator-5554",
    'appium:appPackage': "com.android.documentsui", 
    'appium:appActivity': ".DocumentsActivity'", 
    'appium:automationName': "UiAutomator2
    'appium:automationName': "UIAutomator2"
  }
};

async function Login () {
   const client = await wdio.remote(opts, FlutterDriver);
   const driver = await wdio.remote(androidOptions);
** code is there to access Flutter elements which is working. **
   const fileElement = await driver.element('id', 'com.google.android.documentsui:id/icon_thumb');
   await fileElement.click();
}
Login();

Error seen - User
2024-04-23T12:10:22.837Z INFO webdriver: Initiate new session using the WebDriver protocol
node.js:102
2024-04-23T12:10:22.838Z INFO @wdio/utils: Connecting to existing driver at http://0.0.0.0:4723/
node.js:102
Process exited with code 1
Expecting to select file using element id provided
